# What is "Ext" short for in "Ext Functor"?

Tags: terminology, homological-algebra

Strangely, I've never heard Ext functors referred to by any other name, and so I'm not sure what "Ext" actually means. The only thing I can think of that "Ext" might stand for is "Exterior", which makes a little bit of sense. Does anybody know the meaning and/or history of the term?

Comment: I always thought it was meant to evoke "extension" as in an extension of Hom. Might be wrong though.

Comment: Even simply looking up "[Ext functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor)" on Wikipedia would have given you the answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For given $A,B$ we call a short sequence of the form $$0\to A\to C\to B\to 0$$ an **extension** of $A$ by $B$, the trivial extension being that with $C=A\oplus B$. The Ext functor measures (and gets its name from this) how many inequivalent extensions there are (with equivalence defined by isomorphism of short exact sequences that are the identity on $A$ and $B$).

Comment: This also works for higher Ext groups; see, e.g., Mac Lane's *Homology*, pp. 82–87, or §7.5 in Bourbaki's *Algèbre*, Ch. 10. There is a short discussion in Weibel, 3.4.6.

Comment: Although the terminology you described is the same as what I use, I should mention that some group theorists interchange the pronouns "of" and "by"; they call a group an extension of its quotient by the corresponding kernel.  I'm not sure where or why this alternative convention was introduced; I'm pretty sure it wasn't just to annoy me.

Comment: @AndreasBlass As $A$ is a subobject of $C$ and $B$ usually is not, it seems more naturally to me to call $C$ an extension of $A$, not of $B$ ...

Comment: I agree; "seems more natural" is part of the reason why I use that convention.  Another part of the reason is that in model theory, "extension" is always used in that sense; a structure is an extension of its substructures.